# iTextSharp add many text to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to develop class, which should have a method to add text to page (with different parameters) and this method can be called many times and in result user of class can call a method to get PDF.

My code:

```
public class PdfActions : IPdfActions, IDisposable
{
    PdfReader pdfReader;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter outputWriter;
    Document inputDoc;
    int pageCount;

    public PdfActions(byte[] input)
    {
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(input);
        pageCount = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
        // load the input document
        inputDoc = new Document(pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

        outputWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(inputDoc, ms);
        inputDoc.Open();

        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            inputDoc.SetPageSize(pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
            inputDoc.NewPage();

            PdfContentByte cb = outputWriter.DirectContent;

            PdfImportedPage page = outputWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        }

    }
```

it's constructor, which "copy" PDF to stream

Then my method to add text:

```
    public void AddText(string text, BaseColor color, float x, float y, float fontSize = 12, string font = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.HELVETICA, int alignment = 3, int activePage = 1)
    {
        PdfContentByte cb = outputWriter.DirectContent;

        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(font, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(color);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, fontSize);

        // write the text in the pdf content
        cb.BeginText();
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(alignment, text, x, y, 0);
        cb.EndText();


        PdfImportedPage page = outputWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, activePage);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
```

and method to get PDF byte array:

```
    public byte[] GetPdfOutput()
    {

        inputDoc.Close();
        outputWriter.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

I call it:

```
        _pdfActions = new PdfActions(bytes);
        _pdfActions.AddText("Example, Inc.", BaseColor.Black, x: 185, y: 380, fontSize: 26, font: iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN);
        _pdfActions.AddText("My Address", BaseColor.Black, x: 185, y: 360, fontSize: 16, font: iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN);
        var result = _pdfActions.GetPdfOutput();
```

But it always PDF as template. What is wrong?

PS. I was implemented method AddText as incapsulated (with open stream/actions/close stream), but it does not work with many actions.

Comment: *"But it always PDF as template"* - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not sure what you want the result pdf to be: shall there be one page per `AddText` call? Or shall all `AddText` calls draw on the same result page?